# ajax url won't call php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update the user input ratings through ajax call. This one `alert(performance_rating)` returned the user input ratings properly. But, I have a problem with my url. it won't call user_ratings.php. I don't know why? I have tried alert function in user_ratings.php page. But, it won't alert.

I have the user_ratings.php file in `siteurl.com/include/pages/user_ratings.php`
How do I call my php file properly?

**ajax request**

```
$(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
      performance_rating = $('input:radio[name=rating]:checked').val();
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'user_ratings.php',
        data: {
            rating: performance_rating
        },
        success: function() {
            alert(performance_rating);
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: open console in browser and look at url path in network toolbar when you sending request

Comment: Does the page bearing ajax request exist in the same location as `user_ratings.php`? 
PS: `alert` does NOT work in PHP. Try using `var_dump()` instead.

Comment: This is Javascript. So alert should work fine.

Comment: @BasitSaeed alert does work inside jQuery functions, which is what this is. OP, you need to call your php file from the correct directory in relation to your ajax fire :)

Comment: Where is the file where this function gets called?

Comment: @BenFortune and AndyHolmes, please refer to the OP's question and I quote, "I have tried alert function in user_ratings.php page..."

Comment: try enclosing the php file name in double quotes rather than single quotes..

Comment: give full path of php page in url like 
`url:"http://siteurl.com/include/pages/user_ratings.php"`

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak my php file is in `domain.com/include/pages/user_ratings.php`. I have checked console in browser and my url path is `http://localhost/domain.com/cars/maker/model/user_ratings.php`

Comment: and response type equals to 200?

Comment: you have to use then full url as 
url: 'domain.com/include/pages/user_ratings.php'

Comment: it's look like $("#form") is simple form element. so when you submet this method reload whole page. so try to return false in submit function .on('submit', function (e) {/*some actions*/ return false;});

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending your ajax request from localhost to your domain, then you have to use full site url in your ajax call as follows

```
$(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        performance_rating = $('input:radio[name=rating]:checked').val();
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://domain.com/include/pages/user_ratings.php',
            data: {
                rating: performance_rating
            },
            success: function() {
                alert(performance_rating);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yeah .. Thats right. Now i have edited the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

first its better you do this

```
define("URL", "http://siteurl.com/");
```

Then in the ajax url section write

```
url: '<?php echo URL ;?>includes/pages/user_ratings.php',
```

Comment: I have already tried this. it reload the pages every time. it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Put your [FQDN](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aiuv) (e.g. www.yoururl.com) before the `user_ratings.php` in your jQuery Ajax call. So change to this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
      performance_rating = $('input:radio[name=rating]:checked').val();
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.yoururl.com/user_ratings.php',
        data: {
            rating: performance_rating
        },
        success: function() {
            alert(performance_rating);
        }
      });
    });
});
```